# I'm very new to Blender and have just finished modeling something that contains a lot of holes. But when render or export it, the holes aren't there

Tags: rendering, modifiers, export

[image: Preview]So this is my model in the preview. As you can see, many holes cut into the shape using a Boolean modifier. (Actually very happy with how it turned out). But when I render or export it as a .STL file, those holes are filled in (see below).

[image]
No idea why this is happening, I must have gone wrong somewhere along the way. [Here is my .blend file uploaded to Blend-Exchange.](https://blend-exchange.com/b/aGmVov0y/) If anyone has any bright ideas, I'd love the help.

Comment: Hello, in the file you share the cuboid has no Boolean modifier, please instead share a file with the object before you apply the Boolean

Comment: I've just tested the Boolean and it works fine, so you really need to share your file before the Boolean, and before rendering, apply the Boolean or make sure that the boolean object is hidden

Comment: Your 'Cylinder' ..(cutter?) is hidden to the viewport, but not to the render.

Comment: Was just about to report back with that conclusion! I forgot to delete the "cylinder"! Thanks for the help.

Comment: As @moonboots says, when you're rendering your scene you should stop the boolean object rendering by disabling its monitor icon in the outliner. However, Blender's modifiers can't be exported so if you'r exporting you will need to apply the modifier first and then delete the boolean object otherwise it will be exported with the rest of your objects.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to delete the cutter "cylinder" shape!